# Drupal 7 - Getting referenced entities with a node_load()

Tags: drupal-7

Within the node template, the $node object has the entity next to each 'target_id' value, 
making things nice and easy.

However if I load a node programatically (via node_load) it only has the target_id value, no entity is attached. So I'm having to do a lot of manual load_taxonomy(target_id) to get this.

So clearly Drupal at somepoint in the render pipe-line is doing this automatically, but 
Is there a function I could be calling to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
if ($node = node_load($node_id)) 
{
    $view = node_view($node);
}
```

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7